# implement mutex ensure bounded waiting

Tags: multithreading, mutex

this is an interview question i met which i don't know how to answer it.

first of all what is a bounded waiting mutex, can you give me some examples of a mutex that ensure bounded waiting and doesn't ensure bounded waiting?

secondly, i don't know how to implement it because it seems mutex is a build-in feature of the operating system.

how would you answer this interview question? what kind of atomic operation i can use to implement mutex and how?

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly implement mutexes which time out on top of your OS's never-time-out mutexes. Use the OS-provided mutex to regulate access to your own counter, guaranteeing to always release it quickly.

> repeat
>   ... obtain OS mutex lock on counter
>   ... check counter, see > 0.
>   ... ... if greater than 0, decrement, release OS mutex, return timeout-mutex has been acquired
>   ... release OS mutex lock on counter
>   ... check if timed out
>   ... ... if timed out, return timeout-mutex has timed out
>   ... sleep for some amount of time
>   end repeat

Of course, POSIX mutexes have a trylock function which makes the wait loop trivial.

Busy-waiting is of course a waste of CPU power. More efficient implementations are possible, POSIX has condition variables for example.

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be two usages of "bounded waiting".  [One usage seems to be a simple time-based meaning](http://www.mcs.sdsmt.edu/mcgough/teaching/fall06/456/lectures/Chapter_6.html):

> There is a bound on the wait time for any specific process to enter its critical section.

[Another usage seems to be a thread-count meaning](http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:2QtZ47oakDwJ%3awww.cs.uiuc.edu/class/sp07/cs241/Lectures/10.sync.ppt+bounded+waiting&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESgkXxGEana0BPGtrLrDCvj_ZGiQggmwBTX4apH_nyvjwCXcjI9j2nGIoPYTSXi8dyw7VU5Z_Lg_1430jbpyuf9E1TmTe1iMnB-bYYJN11WeIJy_BJldkq9b26Fj-m9EZfTPTQ4v&sig=AHIEtbTIjNZoitbZCw4RfqBJjtF4ssrTuw):

> A process requesting entry to a critical section should only have to wait for a bounded number of other processes to enter and leave the critical section.

---

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to actually answer the question.  It does seem dependent upon OS primitives.  Maybe they were looking for something like [Peterson's solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm).